# LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) always returns NULL on Galaxy S7 (ONLY)

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Just received a Galaxy S7 (Edge) running Marshmallow (6.0.1) and find that it has an issue with my app that uses `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and targets Sdk Version 22 (Lollipop).  When I call `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation()` it always returns NULL.  Here's what I'm running:

```
public Location getLastKnownLocationObject(Context context) {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    try {
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            // Location is always null on S7 (only)
            Log.i(TAG, ">>> getLastKnownLocationObject() getLastKnownLocation: " + location);
            return location;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, ">>> getLastKnownLocationObject() exception", e);
    }
    return null;

}
```

This same code works fine on every other device I've tried: Galaxy S5 (5.0.1), Nexus 7 (5.0.1), Nexus 9 (6.0.1), and Samsung Tab3 (4.4.2)

Note that if I change the manifest to use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, the above code works fine on every device.  Unfortunately, management won't allow me to change permissions at this time.

In a few answers I've seen here on SO, it's suggested to call the following prior to doing the getLastKnownLocation(), but that didn't have any effect.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
                                // NEVER CALLED on Samsung S7 for LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
                            }
                        });
```

So at the moment, I feel this is an issue exclusive to the new Samsung Galaxy S7.

Comment: Did you tried requesting permissions programmatically since Marshmallow introduced Runtime permission model ?

Comment: My apps target is 22 (Lollipop).

minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 22

Comment: You have to specifically request for permissions on Android Marshmallow and above. Check this post of mine - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856432/asking-for-permissions-while-using-locationmanager/35857017#35857017

Comment: Thanks Shadab... your post shows GPS_PROVIDER, which if I change my manifest permission to ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, works fine with my code and without requesting permissions (I'm targeting Lollipop).

Comment: Please try Fused Location Provider api instead,  available with Google Play Service Framework. That may help.

Comment: Thanks again Shadab... I compiled the Google sample BasicLocationSample that uses the FuseLocationApi: github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location and it DOES work with the "coarse" permission to properly return last location!  So that is a possible solution.  We're not a fan of bringing in more of the Google Play Services than necessary as we're always battling dex count, we already use "ads"... just need to add "location"... :)

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'

Comment: Cool. Good to hear that  :)

Comment: So adding just the location service from Play Services (compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0') added over 4600 methods to the .apk.  That's a pretty big hit to take just to support a Samsung S7 :)

Answer (score 3):

From my experience with Samsung devices. If you reboot the phone and you DON'T enable GPS you will not get a location. If you enable GPS as some point - maybe by running Google Maps, then you will get a location. Samsung does not return a location for GPS, Network or Passive providers unless it has gotten a location during the devices power on cycle.

None of the calls I have made in code ever get it to kick in and activate and get a location. They work fine on other devices. Samsung does not seem to cache this information for very long either.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are calling `isProviderEnabled()` so at least that is covered and using the network location should be enabled. However the exact wording of the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#isProviderEnabled(java.lang.String)) is:

> "If the user has enabled this provider in the Settings menu, true is
>   returned otherwise false is returned"

So it's just about the provider being "enabled" as in not being turned off by the user.

Does the problematic phone (the S7) have a SIM card inside? It's possible that on that specific device the network based positioning requires a SIM card or internet connection.

Referring to the the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html#requiresCell()) you could check what these return:

```
locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).requiresCell();
locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).requiresNetwork();
```

And of course just calling `getLastKnownLocation()` will return `null` if the location is unknown. And it's unknown if no application (yours or some other) has specifically requested the device to determine its location. So the suggestion to call `requestLocationUpdates()` is the correct advice. But it may take a while to determine the location so calling `getLastKnownLocation()` right after probably still returns `null`.

And even if it returns something, it might be very old data that's not even valid anymore. So why not just [subscribe to receive location updates](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)? That's the way it's intended. You are using network based positioning so it won't (at all/significantly) affect power consumption and the updates won't come too often if you specify time interval and distance limits that suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help... there are now 2 different Galaxy S7's that I've been able to test on, both are fully functional cell phones with Internet access (and are on two different carriers, not that that means anything).  I have no issue obtaining GPS coordinates with other apps.  And do note that if I change permissions to ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION there isn't any issue.
I did try the .requiresCell() and .requiresNetwork() and interestingly they both return True on the S7, but both calls return false on all the other devices I test on.

Comment: (and I don't need to subscribe to updates as I just need a rough location for a weather app)

Comment: You can of course call `removeUpdates()` once you have received the fresh and up-to-date location in the `onLocationChanged()` callback and you won't then receive further updates. That would be the solution for cases when `getLastKnownLocation()` returns null.

Comment: Actually our code does as you suggest and does request location updates if last known location would ever happen to be null (which we have never actually seen until the S7).  The problem I'm seeing with this is that onLocationChanged() is never fired on the **S7** when requesting location from NETWORK_PROVIDER.  `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);`
This is with the manifest permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.  If I do change it to ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, that code works as expected.