# How do I send POST requests from Android to my application server?

Tags: android, http, post

```
private class HttpPostTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpURLConnection mHttpCon = null;
        String result = null;

        try {
            mHttpCon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL("http://192.168.1.4:8888/about")
                    .openConnection()));
            mHttpCon.setDoOutput(true);
            mHttpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            mHttpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
            mHttpCon.connect();

            OutputStream mOS = mHttpCon.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter mWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(mOS, "UTF-8"));
            mWriter.write("{'username':'test','fcmid':'fdjslkfjds09f'}");
            mWriter.flush();
            mWriter.close();
            mOS.flush();
            mOS.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm using the code shown above and as far as I can see it is not sent **at all**. Wireshark doesn't even show anything sent by the IP address of the phone I have the app running on. I can receive requests from the iOS app, but fail to even send anything from Android. Am I doing something wrong? All the tutorials I looked through use HttpClient or AndroidHttpClient, which don't even seem to be available anymore.

Comment: Use `Volley` or `Retrofit2` . `HttpClient ` already deprecated .

Comment: Are you starting the task using execute()? Did you included INTERNET permissions ?

Comment: @ShadabAnsari Yes, I did both.

Comment: What is the device OS version ?

Comment: @ShadabAnsari Android N developer preview (Nexus 6) and Android Marshmallow (Nexus 5 Emulator)

Comment: You need to ask for permissions programmatically too since you are using Android M +. check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856432/asking-for-permissions-while-using-locationmanager/35857017#35857017

Comment: @ZahidulIslam It's working with Volley! Is this considered the new way to do this?

Comment: @mkocs , Google suggeset developer to use `Volley` instead of `HttpClient` . Take a look here https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: @ZahidulIslam Well, thanks then

Comment: @ShadabAnsari , as far as i know , For internet the permission is not necessary .

Comment: @ZahidulIslam No, you are wrong, it is required.

Answer (score 0):

@mkocs You are to forward buddy as persmission structure is changed since android M you had to ask for critical permission in android